# How to fix symfony 1.4 error "Empty response header name, aborting request" after updating to php 7

Tags: symfony-1.4, php-7, apache2.4

I have recently updated my server to ubuntu 16 which has apache2.4 and php7.0 My project is built with symfony 1.4 which works fine on my old server (ubuntu 14, php5.x). Now suddenly stopped working after update with error "Empty response header name, aborting request".

Comment: also, the API's are working fine with JSON data as a response

Comment: Which distribution of symfony1 are you using? The fork at https://github.com/punkave/symfony1 has had some PHP7 compatibility changes made to it.

Can you post a full(er) stack trace of what you're seeing?

Comment: I've tried the distribution you shared but didn't work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work for me"? If you share details of the incompatibilities we can make sure to get them fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I altered some core files of Symfony by replacing methods which are removed in php7 such as preg_replace() which somehow caused the error "Empty response header name, aborting request".

however, I have solved the issue by downgrading php7 to 5.6 using https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php 
everything's working now.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error was generated by the `addHtmlHead` method of the `sfViewConfigHandler` class (`lib/vendor/symfony/lib/config/sfConfigHandler.class.php`).

I modified the file `app/frontend/config/view.yml` removing default:
  `http_metas: content-type: text/html` and I added the meta tag in the layout.

Comment: Please, correct the path to appS/frontend/config/view.yml with S. Thank you.